# Best Api structure approach for multiple chapters having multiple topics(and each topic further have pdf for each ) in ExpressJs?

Tags: node.js, api, express

What should be the api structure if i have multiple chapters which further contain multiple topics for each chapter, and this topics have 1 pdf for each? I'm using Express.

I have **two tables** in database, one have chapters list in it and second have all the topics and pdf.(second table is referenced to first table).

I'm using **ExpressJs** with **ejs** template engine.

The structure should be in a way so that i don't have to run multiple nested loops to display them.

May be my question is little immature(coz i'm begineer), but i'll be **thankfull** if you answer

Comment: In the title you are asking about API and then later you mention ejs templating engine. Are you looking for an API routing structure or avoiding EJS looping? Can you add more information to the question?

Comment: I am making an applictaion for online courses. And i'm using expressJs for that, now i need to create an api structure which should have all the chapters of a perticular course and these chapters have multiple topic in them where each topic have a pdf. So how could i make that api?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that you are confused. To make it clear:

a) When you are talking about creating API's in Express.js, you won't render the output using a templating engine like EJS. Instead, you would output data directly in the form of JSON etc.
b) You will need client-side coding to request data from this API's. The best example would be a front-end application in ReactJS or Vue.js etc. or a mobile app.

Now, talking about the structure of your routes, you might want to have:

```
/api/chapters (to get all chapters)  
/api/chapters/:chapterId (to get chapter details with all topics) 
/api/topic/:topicId (to get topic details with pdf link)
```

If you are displaying all chapters with topic details and they are nested, then there is no way to avoid two nested loops. I don't see any downside in it.

Tip: To get all chapters with topics in one query, you can use [lookup](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-use-the-lookup-function-in-mongodb-1277).

Comment: Yeah i messed up my question with that ejs thing. But i'm not using react instead i'm using axios to query the api. Thanks a lot